# ActiveRecord: avoid instantiate objects on query response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Is there a direct way to avoid instantiate objects when make a query?

I would like to get an array of hashes instead of an array of ActiveRecord objects without instantiate stage to improve performance.

For now, I'm doing it like this example:

```rb
sql = User.where(name: 'John', ...).to_sql
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
```

Is there a magic method like: `User.where(name: 'John', ...).skip_instantiation.to_a` ?

Answer (score 2):

What about pluck: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck

```
Customer.where(code: ["Bob01", "Fred01"]).pluck(:id, :code, :name)

#    (0.4ms)  SELECT "customers"."id", "customers"."code", "customers"."name" FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."code" IN ($1, $2)  [["code", "Bob01"], ["code", "Fred01"]]
# => [[1, "Bob01", "Bob Bobson"], [2, "Fred01", "Fred Fredson"]]
```

If you want an array of hashes then what about:

```
columns = [:id, :code, :name]
Customer.
    where(code: ["Bob01", "Fred01"]).
    pluck(*columns).
    map {|row| columns.zip(row).to_h }

# => [{:id=>1, :code=>"Bob01", :name=>"Bob Bobson"}, {:id=>2, :code=>"Fred01", :name=>"Fred Fredson"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

To map SQL results into an array of hashes you can use the `OpenStruct` class.

```rb
require 'ostruct'

query = "SELECT * FROM USERS"

results = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)

mapped = results.map {|r| OpenStruct.new(r)}
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html

Answer (score 1):

I have added this method to `ActiveRecord::Relation` class:

```rb
# config/initializers/active_record_relation.rb
ActiveRecord::Relation.class_eval do
  def run_sql
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(to_sql).to_a
  end
end
```

Now I can run queries without instantiate objects:

```rb
User.select('name as custom_name').run_sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `.pluck`, [as Ben Stephens outlined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64757961/3319298).

I want to go into more detail about cases where it may not be sufficient, however.

**Case 1**, what if I want to pluck data from a joined table's column?
**A:** Easy, use string arguments:

```
User.where(name: 'John', ...).joins(:posts).pluck(:id, "#{Post.table_name}.message")
```

**Case 2**, what if I want to pluck arbitrary SQL, for example, a value from a hash in a JSONB column?
**A:** A bit more convoluted. First of all, `.pluck` does not support arbitrary SQL, so you'll have to use `.select`. Second, it is important to specify a name for the arbitrary "column" being selected with `AS something` SQL statement. Third, to skip instantiation of AR objects, use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` as others have suggested. Putting it together:

```
sql = User.where(name: 'John', ...).select(:id, "(metadata->'age')::integer AS age").to_sql
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
#=> [{"id" => 1, "age" => 28}]
```